# Excel: How do i concatinate a string and a int into one

Tags: excel

Hi i am trying to solve a problem that has been perplexing me for quite a bit.

I have:

```
Cell A     Cell B
Int         String
```

What i want is:

Cell C

```
 int string
```

I have explored using the concatinate function but what it does is convert the int to a string as well.  Thank you for any help!

Comment: There is no way to format the cell in a way to keep the int as a number and add the string.  If the string is constant then you can use a custom format for the cell.  But the string would need to be a constant or variable based on the number.

Answer (score 0):

try below

```
C2=A2&" "&B2
```

Comment: To stick with your "concatenate" theme, Damith is right, but it is represented as such: `C2 = CONCATENATE(A2," ",B2)`

Comment: this does sort of work,  the issue is that if i do that equation. I am fairly sure the int value gets changed to a string value in memory.  So it will look how i want it, but i have another program that i run my worksheet through that is running into errors because it gets converted into a string instead of remaining a int.